# Как склоняется женская фамилия Худайбердиева?

Tags: ономастика, морфология

-

Answer (score 4):

И.п. Худайбердиева. 
Р.п. Худайбердиевой. 
Д.п. Худайбердиевой. 
В.п. Худайбердиеву. 
Т.п. Худайбердиевой. 
П.п. о Худайбердиевой.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу иначе ответить... г-ну [[@grumant](/users/1349/grumant)](/users/1349/grumant)

> Ара Грачьевич Геворгян

Мслаченко Владимир **Никитович** - советский футболист, 
Тоже будете в пример ставить?

Есть правила образования отчеств - и есть отчества, образованные **вопреки** правилам.
Вы упорно давите на второе.
А по правилам при образовании отчеств от иностранных имен последняя ударная гласная нормативно сохраняется. Примеры я вам приводил.

Кстати, от *Амангельды* отчество - *Амангельд**ы**евич*. Ваш пример и тут неудачен.
Чтобы не сказать - неверен. 
[Мусабаев Талгат Амангельдыевич](http://www.walkinspace.ru/index/0-770)